# gdb attach to process in windows not working

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, gdb

I am trying to debug a library for a third party software. I have the source code of the library and I have compiled it using -g. I need to start the software to use the library and debug. AFAIK I have to start the program, then from gdb use attach and the id of the process. I am doing this, but gdb says "Can't attach to process".
Does anyone know why might this be happening?

Comment: what about starting process inside gdb.

Comment: I played with this a bit. I can attach to most processes, but not, for example, to running calc.exe. I can debug it by starting it from gdb, though. Wonder why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try to start it with `gdb`, just inside, having it attached in the gdb call.

```
gdb your_program_name
run your_parameter1 your_paremeter2...
```

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem. I was giving it a wrong sentence. When I used "attach PID" it freeze, but I solved by updating gdb. Now it works perfectly.